# How do I ask these questions?

Tags: наречия

I would like to say to my girlfriend's mother in Russian (via Skype):

"Are any of your flowers still alive?"

"I would like to you to visit us in Atlanta soon.   I will pay for your trip."

How do I say this?  If you type it in Russian letters, I can pronounce it.

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't consider it to be a proper question...

Ваши цветы все ещё живы?

It doesn't sound polite, I believe, in both languages.

Я бы хотел, чтобы Вы приехали к нам в Атланту. Я оплачу поездку.

Answer (score 2):

1) No one says about flowers. Only reason to say it, you exactly know she is loving flowers.
better ask smth like : Как ваши дела? or Как вы поживаете?
it means approximatly "how are u?" or "how its going?"

2) "Я бы хотел (I want)", чтобы Вы приехали к нам в Атланту. Я оплачу поездку.

you can say " Мы " instead " Я " cos " Мы " means " We " you and your girlfrend together
    Мы хотим, чтобы Вы приехали к нам в Атланту. Я оплачу поездку.

You can say also " Приезжайте в гости к нам в Атланту. Я оплачу поездку"

"в гости" means  You want them as guests in your house